# Questions about gather and rename function

Tags: r, tidyr

1. While practicing the gather function with the examples in gather document.
   I found the result is not automatically named as stock and price I gave in the gather function argument. Thus I'll have to use mutate or rename function after that. 
   Is that per design or how can I get the name there with gather function?
   I also checked the question previously asked, [tidyr gather: simultaneously gather and rename key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901442/tidyr-gather-simultaneously-gather-and-rename-key#new-answer),  however, I tried the answer provided by Steven, but it will show:

   > Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) :
   >   names do not match previous names" when I do gather.
2. For `rename` function, do we have to specify every name even though I only want to rename certain columns?
   It shows

   > Error: All arguments to rename must be named.

So looks like I need to assign to the same name itself if I don't want to change some column name?

I am using Mac with Rstudio v0.98.1103, tidyr v0.20, dplyr v0.41

```
library(dplyr)
# From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181060
stocks <- data.frame(
    time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
    X = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
    Y = rnorm(10, 0, 2),
    Z = rnorm(10, 0, 4)
)

gather(stocks, stock, price, -time)
```

similar questions in another thread,[Can't change the column names outputted by "gather" to be anything other than the default names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26130751/cant-change-the-column-names-outputted-by-gather-to-be-anything-other-than-th?rq=1)

I tried to detach `plyr` but still not working.

[image: stock_long1 result]

[image: stocks result]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598113/why-doesnt-gather-use-the-key-variable-name?rq=1 Update the package with update.packages() can solve thi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do get the right result of stock and price names with

```
library(tidyr) # You had put dplyr
library(dplyr) # For the pipes %>%

# From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181060
stocks <- data.frame(
  time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
  X = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
  Y = rnorm(10, 0, 2),
  Z = rnorm(10, 0, 4)
)

stocks_long1 <- stocks %>%
  gather(stock, price, -time)

stocks_long1
```

If what you want to rename is X, Y and/or Z, then you can do

```
# Rename before gathering
stocks_long2 <- stocks %>%
  rename(X1=X, Y1=Y, Z1=Z) %>%
  gather(stock, price, -time)

stocks_long2
```

Hope this helps

**EDIT:**

If you don't want the `time` variable, you can do something like

```
stocks_long3 <- stocks %>%
  gather(stock, price, -time) %>%
  select(-time)

stocks_long3
```

Comment: I run the code you provided with stocks_long1 but the name is still variable and value, the time is not removed. I am confused what makes the difference.

    > stocks_long1
         time variable   value
        1  2009-01-01        X -0.5325
        2  2009-01-02        X -0.2173

Comment: Try putting `tidyr::gather` instead of just `gather`. I got the right result, so maybe you are having some problems with masking the function or something like that.

Comment: I tried with tidyr::gather but still got the same result :(,  Thanks for your advice, so looks like I can try to find some resource about the masking to solve this? Really appreciate for your answer.

Comment: No problem. Could you edit your question and add the result you get when you run `stocks_long1` (and also `stocks`)? Do you get any errors/warnings? Something _really_ weird is going on.

Comment: looks like it's the package version issue, it's fixed with later tidyr version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32598113/why-doesnt-gather-use-the-key-variable-name?rq=1    really thanks for you help.